# c# - Custom type Convert.ToString

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having trouble when rendering a text box using `@Html.TextBoxFor` with a custom type I've created. My custom type looks like this:

```
public class Encrypted<T>
{
    private readonly Lazy<T> _decrypted;
    private readonly Lazy<string> _encrypted;

    public static implicit operator Encrypted<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Encrypted<T>(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Encrypted<T> value)
    {
        return value._encrypted.Value;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then on my model, I have:

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public Encrypted<string> Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I manually populate the value in my controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ExampleModel
    {
        Name = "Example Name";
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Then on my view I have the standard `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)`. However, when that renders, the value of my text box gets set to: Services.Encrypted`1[System.String]`

Presumably this is because I'm using a custom type and the compiler doesn't know how to convert my type to a string value.

I've tried using a custom `TypeConverter`:

```
public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
{
    return destinationType == typeof(string);
}

public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
{
    if (destinationType == typeof(string))
    {
        var encrypted = value as IEncrypted;
        if (encrypted != null)
        {
            return encrypted.DecryptedValue();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then on my Encrypted model I added:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EncryptedTypeConveter))]
```

However it doesn't seem to be using the custom `TypeConverter`. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override `ToString()`.

Comment: Hi SLaks, thanks for the comment. I am already overriding the `ToString()` method - I've updated my original post to include the code snippet.

Comment: @Scrooby You're not actually overriding the ToString method when you used the `new` keyword; that's called "hiding".  To override, you have to use the `override` keyword.

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice - you're absolutely right. That was a real face palm moment. Thanks!